# How do I know when my applications for disaster relief loans have been approved?

Tags: united-states, loans, small-business, covid-19, sba

I applied to all 3 programs as I have a business in NYC:

- SBA EIDL - Economic Injury Disaster Loan Emergency Advance
- PPP - Paycheck Protection Program
- NYC Small Business Continuity Program

I think I received the EIDL as my bank account says:

```
SBAD Treasury 310 ....
```

But how do I know for sure this is the EIDL? I did not receive any confirmation email or anything.

As for the PPP and NYC Small Business Continuity Loan. What do I need to look out for when these are approved as it doesn't look like they send out confirmation emails or anything. Is there an easy way to check the status on these loans?

And most of all, which of these programs are fully forgiven as in free money?